# What are the various types of science & engineering qualifications that Batman has?

Tags: dc, batman

Is there any DC comic or any other authoritative source that states/lists the various science & engineering qualifications that Batman has?

EDIT:

*I see that this question is on hold. However, please note that this question is not a duplicate. A question similar to this was asked previously but it did not specifically ask for the Batman's engineering & science qualifications.Consequently the answers did not address this topic( Batman's engineering & science qualifications) either*.

Comment: What are the various types of intelligence?

Comment: Very high IQ...emotional intelligence, though...not so much

Comment: I have edited the question. I am interested in knowing about his engineering and science qualifications.Thanks.

Comment: @phantom42 I went through that question that you have stated. But it does not list his engineering or science qualifications.

Comment: is there a reason you assume he *has* an engineering or science degree? the answer on the other question discusses what degrees he has, and where he went to school.